Connect virtual machines on different physical nodes using VLAN
I am quite new to linux networking and still trying to understand it. So, apologies if the answer for the problem is simple.
I have SSH access of two physical nodes which are present in the same network, let's call them node1 and node2. Networking for them is configured using netplan and they can ping each other.
The netplan for them looks like as shown below
network:
  ethernets:
    switchports:
      match:
        name: eno*
  bonds:
    bond0:
      interfaces: [switchports]
      mtu: 8900
      parameters:
        down-delay: 0
        lacp-rate: fast
        mii-monitor-interval: 100
        mode: 802.3ad
        transmit-hash-policy: layer2+3
        up-delay: 0
  vlans:
    bond0.12:
      id: 12
      link: bond0
      mtu: 8900
      addresses: [10.12.14.12/28]
      gateway4: 10.12.14.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 8.8.8.8

Please note name of the bond and vlan is different for both the physical nodes. I am creating few virtual machines on each physical node and want them to connect with each other.
To do so, I tried to create same named vlan and bridge on both physical nodes and attached the bridge to these virtual machines. After these changes netplan looks like something as shown below for both physical node. Please note, names for earlier defined bond and vlan is still different in both physical nodes.
network:
  ethernets:
    switchports:
      match:
        name: eno*
  bonds:
    bond0:
      interfaces: [switchports]
      mtu: 8900
      parameters:
        down-delay: 0
        lacp-rate: fast
        mii-monitor-interval: 100
        mode: 802.3ad
        transmit-hash-policy: layer2+3
        up-delay: 0
  vlans:
    bond0.12:
      id: 12
      link: bond0
      mtu: 8900
      addresses: [10.12.14.12/28]
      gateway4: 10.12.14.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 8.8.8.8
    bond0.15:
      id: 15
      link: bond0
      addresses:
        - 192.168.10.1/24
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.10.1
          metric: 100
          on-link: true
  bridges:
    vmbr1:
      interfaces: [ bond0.15 ]
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 0
        stp: false

After this I added a routing table rule to allow routing from new vlan interface but it did not work.
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i bond0.15 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o bond0.15 -j MASQUERADE

I am not sure, what I need to do here so virtual machines on different physical nodes can ping each other.

Is the switch in between the hosts configured for those VLANs?

do you mean physical switch? I don't have access for physical switch. I am not sure about what we mean by those VLANs. But if you see there is already an existing VLAN available, in this case it's bond0.12. This VLAN as ip address of physical node.

So the hosts are directly connected? You're not making too much sense.

Yes, they are. Apologies, if I am not so much clear. My problem is that, I want VMs on different nodes to communicate with each other. These VMs are using different range of private ip address compared to physical nodes. If I use just linux bridge, VMs are able to reach internet.
As I want VMs to reach each other, I created same named VLAN on both of them having same range of IP but still they are not able to communicate with each other. Also, with new VLAN VMs are not reaching internet. Eventhough, routing rule is added using iptables

Routing rules? Iptables doesn't do any routing. It only does filtering and translation before and after routing, but it doesn't handle the actual routing.

Noted. Apologies for my confusion. Still, I am not sure why VMs attached to vlan via bridge are not able to access outside network or the VMs on the same vlan on different node.

Is the VLAN configured on the hypervisor? Is the VLAN's configured on the switches? If not, it won't work.

I like this, this is a cool idea. Am I understanding your setup correctly, you have several cables between the nodes and you're bonding them? Does the bond work without the vlans? Do the vlans work if you use a single interface without a bond?

@vidarlo VLAN's name differs on all machines and I can't configure them on switch. So looks IPSec is an available option for me.

@RobM Ideally Yes, but still i don't have access for switch so I can't do much from machine. Unless, I go with some tunneling.

I don't think I did understand your setup, it sounds like you don't have cables going directly between your nodes, it sounds like they're both connected to switches managed by your service provider, using their vlans. In that case, trying to configure more vlans on the bond interface isn't going to get you anywhere, using tunnels is a good idea, or you could try a "vlan in a vlan" setup

Agree. Tunneling would be one way but that won't be good idea in my case. I will explore vlan stacking

If you want to use a new vlan, you need to configure all switch devices you go through with this vlan in their database and on the trunk for the machine port, so if you don't have access to the network devices you should find another way.
You could either use the vlan 12, or try to tunnel the VM traffic to the other hypervisor in wireguard / ipsec / evpn.
The easiest thing to do is to use the vlan 12.
Your issue here is that you need your layer 2 domain to communicate with the switch, without reaching any layer 3 termination.
Your bond 0.12 is a layer 3 termination.
So you want to add the whole bond to your bridge, and then create your vlan on the bridge directly. This should looks like this (untested):
network:
  ethernets:
    switchports:
      match:
        name: eno*
  bonds:
    bond0:
      interfaces: [switchports]
      mtu: 8900
      parameters:
        down-delay: 0
        lacp-rate: fast
        mii-monitor-interval: 100
        mode: 802.3ad
        transmit-hash-policy: layer2+3
        up-delay: 0
  vlans:
    vmbr1.12:
      id: 12
      link: vmbr1
      mtu: 8900
      addresses: [10.12.14.12/28]
      gateway4: 10.12.14.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 8.8.8.8
  bridges:
    vmbr1:
      interfaces: [ bond0 ]
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 0
        stp: false

Keep in mind that your layer 3 (network) can be encapsulated in layer 2 (data link), but you cannot do the opposite.
Take care, this is the kind of network change where you could lose your ssh connection if you do any mistake, so it would be safer to script a rollback after some time, or to connect with serial / kvm / idrac.


Vlans on machines are different. Jut the bond name is same. So, i don't think this will work but yeah IPsec and VPN approach will work. I may have to take a look at these approaches and how they can work in my case.

I didn't understood the machines were in 2 different vlans. You indeed need a tunneling approach then, but you first need to know if the router that will make your vlans communicate is also a firewall. If yes, you might need to ask the network team to add a rule for your tunneling approach (one udp port for wireguard, or ESP+IKE for ipsec, or one udp port for VxLAN). Do you think they will create a rule for you?

No they will not

You need to test what protocol can go from host A to host B then. Can you ping? If you install nginx on A, can you curl A from B? What about ports udp 4789, 51820, 450 and 4500?
